# Valgrind output report

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm quite new with C++ and i realized a program, with the ITK library for medical imaging. It has a high computational cost and at the end of the running, my laptop seems to lost speed and functionality. This is the Valgrind output:

```
==6258== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6258==     in use at exit: 3,573,521 bytes in 25,493 blocks
==6258==   total heap usage: 271,050 allocs, 245,557 frees, 5,231,125,547 bytes allocated
==6258== 
==6258== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6258==    definitely lost: 283,640 bytes in 11,812 blocks
==6258==    indirectly lost: 3,101,916 bytes in 11,816 blocks
==6258==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6258==    still reachable: 187,965 bytes in 1,865 blocks
==6258==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

I know that it is not perfect and not all of the memory blocks are deallocated, but i want to know if these results could be tragic or they do not affect the performance of the PC, so much.
My laptop has a 4Gb of RAM, quadcore.

Comment: If your program is finished, PC performance should gradually return to normal, regardless of what the program did. If this is what happens, you should not worry. If not, please describe the symptoms that you see. In addition, which operating system are you using?

Comment: After some minutes seems that PC perfomance returned normal. I'm using Linux Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.